# Subreport could not be shown

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I am using VS 2017 and doing a sub report for the first time. I have 2 reports that each run correctly on their own but once I make the second a sub report I get the error sub report could not be shown.

I have already cleared the report cache, ensured that the parameters that I am passing have the same name as the sub report is calling for.  I am using a newer version of VS so I don't believe that I could be having the issue of using the same data set. Both of my reports have been deployed on the same server.
I have confirmed that the report parameters that I am sending are correct. I have also defaulted the sub report parameters just in case they aren't making it across.

The last thing that I have tried was to just make my sub report display text and I am still getting Error: Subreport couldn't not be shown.

I am not sure what code I could show but if you need something that I haven't provided please let me know.

Comment: How is your subreport referred to in the main report?  I often have issues with naming.  Perhaps when you developed the report on your local machine, the subreport links to a local folder when it needs to link to the report manager folder.  Even better, use a [relative path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/specifying-paths-to-external-items-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) and avoid any confusion.

Comment: I just figured it out. My sub report needed the connection string passed to it. Thanks for your help though!!